# Autodesk-Forge Publish multiple models to BIM 360 using the Data Management API

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-data-management

I am trying to create a postman set of collections that will be able to publish all the models in our companies directory everyday without having to publish each of them manually. So far I have been able to extract the project id and item id of each of the project models and publish it but haven't been able to provide a list of project ids to the json body.

Comment: you are referring to this publish API, right ? ... https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/tutorials/publish-model/

Comment: Yes that is the tutorial that I have been following.

Answer (score 0):

I would start with this demo code. https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/custom-bim-360-search-elasticsearch

It does about 80% of what you need.  If attaches a webhook and listens for new files added to your BIM360 projects.  On change, it downloads and indexes meta-data files. You could use the same mechanism to get the project id and ItemId and trigger the publish API.

Does that help?

Comment: That does help for new projects but we needed to publish existing models in BIM 360 on a daily basis.

Comment: The web hook, in that demo, will trigger for new models, but also for existing models that are updated.  That will cover the same mechanism for acquiring the project and item Id, you are looking for, I believe.

Comment: Does the webhook technique answer your question regarding existing models, or would you like me to explain in more detail ?

Comment: I apologize for the late response but I managed to create a python code that uses "requests" to make requests to the forge api and publish models in the desired folders. Then scheduled this python script to run every morning. So it works now and thank you very much for your guidance and help.

Comment: Awesome news !  Thanks Josh.

Comment: I'd love to see what code you're using to accomplish this - I'm working on a similar thing myself. Any chance you would share with me?